Проблема со сценарием ввода с помощью perl -e 'print'
Я пытаюсь автоматизировать ввод в программу с помощью perl, вводя в командной строке perl -e 'print "1\n5\nn\n5\n"' | ./game_of_chance.

Но в конце вывода функции print почему то программа останавливается, и ввести что-либо невозможно

Должно быть:

Проблема вряд ли в программе, тк если я выберу сценарий, в котором print заканичвается на выборе цифры в игре, то тоже возникнет проблема, хоть и слегка другая:

В идеале после выбора игры должно быть:

После выбора цифры:

При этом, если последним действием я поставлю выбрать пункт "7" в меню (то есть выход), то все действия в списке завершатся корректно. Что интересно при этом можно даже не ставить \n в конце (perl -e 'print "1\n5\nn\n7"' | ./game_of_chance), хотя логика программы требует подтвердить действия с помощью Enter

После завершения perl-а его stdout закрывается, соответственно закрывается и stdin в вашей программе. Если вы хотите далее продолжить чтение из терминала, то его надо открыть и соеденить этот файл с stdin (Кстати,  в какой ОС делаете программу и опишите поподробнее какой интерфейс (откуда что и когда вводите, куда собираетесь выводить) с ней все же хотите сделать)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать? Это задание из книги "Искусство эксплойта". Изначально мне нужно выполнить такой ввод  perl -e 'print "1\n5\nn\n5\n" . "A"x100 . pack("q", 0xffff) . "1/nn/n" . "7\n"' | ./game_of_chance, где 0xfff это адрес функции на выйгришь Jackpot. То есть я делаю переполнение буфера и меняю адрес вызова функции игры "Выбери номер". Но эти части принта не получается связать, они после " сразу сбивают запись, как показано ранее. Мне бы еще в идеале знать как после ввода с perl print вбивать дальше данные вручную для общего ознакомления. OS - Kali Linux

"Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?"
Поскольку речь идет о вводе с терминала, то это не сложно, т.к. широко известно, что в *nix-ах терминал, с которого  запущена программа,   имеет в ней имя /dev/tty.
Просто откроем его и свяжем наш уже существующий FILE *stdin с новым дескриптором.
Для того, чтобы новый stdin оказался связанным с используемым по умолчанию для stdin дескриптором с номером 0  используем вызов dup2, а чтобы не плодить не используемые дескрипторы закроем уже дапнутый дескиптор, полученный  от открытого /dev/tty
(надеюсь, что вам, как начинающему хакеру, юзающему эксплойты, не составит большого труда разобраться в этих нехитрых системных манипуляциях)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char s[1000];

  while (fgets(s, 1000, stdin))
    printf("s = %s", s);
  puts("\nstdin EOF, reopen tty");

  int fd = open("/dev/tty", O_RDONLY);
  stdin = fdopen(dup2(fd, 0), "r");
  close(fd);
  
  puts("Enter lines:");
  while (fgets(s, 1000, stdin))
    printf("s: %s", s);

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}


Если я правильно понял вашу проблему, то вам должен подойти модуль Term::ReadKey и/или Term::ReadLine
use v5.26.0;
use warnings;
use Term::ReadKey;

ReadMode 4; # Turn off controls keys
my $key;
while (not defined ($key = ReadKey(-1))) {
    # No key yet
}
print "Get key $key\n";
ReadMode 0; # Reset tty mode before exiting

Подробности, как всегда, на metacpan: https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadKey

он делает пример с 185 странцы, подаёт на input с помощью perl
